# CSS Data-Transition to anchors

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

I've been trying to use the data-transition option for anchors on my horizontal page layout but have been unsuccessful. I'm trying to give the content a nice slide effect when the anchor link is selected. They layout of the page is horizontal. Is using transitions only available for pages and not anchors? Also when the text is longer than the viewport would it be possible to have the anchor link jump to the top of the anchor regardless of where the user was positioned before on a previous link/anchor?

Here's the **HTML**

```
<div id="header">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a class="anchor" href="#box1" data-transition="slide">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="anchor" href="#box2" data-transition="slide">About Us </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="box1"><a name="box1"></a> 
            <div class="contentcontainer">
                    <div class="contentccrightcontainer">

                         <h1 class="blue">Home</h1> litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse sit amet ultricies nulla. Phasellus vel felis nec neque ultricies condimentum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Ut pretium tincidunt nulla, eu vestibulum sem malesuada in. Maecenas consequat eros dolor, nec luctus lectus dignissim vel. Maecenas placerat mollis arcu, feugiat pharetra leo adipiscing sed. Curabitur eget varius libero, ac tristique justo.


<h1 class="blue">Home</h1>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam sit amet est justo. Maecenas eget cursus sapien. Fusce in nisi elementum, rhoncus odio quis, placerat velit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse sit amet ultricies nulla. Phasellus vel felis nec neque ultricies condimentum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Ut pretium tincidunt nulla, eu vestibulum sem malesuada in. Maecenas consequat eros dolor, nec luctus lectus dignissim vel. Maecenas placerat mollis arcu, feugiat pharetra leo adipiscing sed. Curabitur eget varius libero, ac tristique justo.

                </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        <!--- Section 2 -->

    <div id="box2"><a name="box2"></a> 
            <div class="contentcontainer">
                    <div class="contentccrightcontainer">

                         <h1 class="blue">About Us</h1> litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse sit amet ultricies nulla. Phasellus vel felis nec neque ultricies condimentum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Ut pretium tincidunt nulla, eu vestibulum sem malesuada in. Maecenas consequat eros dolor, nec luctus lectus dignissim vel. Maecenas placerat mollis arcu, feugiat pharetra leo adipiscing sed. Curabitur eget varius libero, ac tristique justo.


<h1 class="blue">About Us</h1>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam sit amet est justo. Maecenas eget cursus sapien. Fusce in nisi elementum, rhoncus odio quis, placerat velit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse sit amet ultricies nulla. Phasellus vel felis nec neque ultricies condimentum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Ut pretium tincidunt nulla, eu vestibulum sem malesuada in. Maecenas consequat eros dolor, nec luctus lectus dignissim vel. Maecenas placerat mollis arcu, feugiat pharetra leo adipiscing sed. Curabitur eget varius libero, ac tristique justo.

                </div>
                </div>
            </div>     
    </div>
```

Here's the **CSS**

```
.contentcontainer {
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 15px 1px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 15px 1px #000;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    width: 940px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    top: 65px
}
.contentccleft {
    padding-top: 35px;
    float: left;
    position:relative;
    margin-left:15px;
    width: 425px;
}
.contentccright {
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 35px;
    width: 350px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
.contentccrightcontainer {
    position: relative;
    width: 840px;
    background:#eaeaea;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    overflow:auto;
}
#header {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    z-index: 2000;
    height: 55px;
    position:fixed;
    margin: 0 0;
}
#menu {
    width: 940px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
ul li {
    list-style: none;
    height: 50px;
    float:left;
    padding:0 0;
}
ul li a {
    font-family: font3;
    width: 134px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 53px;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #636393;
    color: #fff;
    font-size:13px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transition: .2s all linear;
    -moz-transition: .2s all linear;
    -o-transition: .2s all linear;
    transition: .2s all linear;
}
li:nth-child(1) a {
    border-color: #fff;
}
li:nth-child(2) a {
    border-color: #FF6;
}

li:nth-child(1) a:hover, li:nth-child(1) a.active {
    color: #000;
    border-bottom: 55px solid #fff;
    height: 1px;
}
li:nth-child(2) a:hover, li:nth-child(2) a.active {
    color: #000;
    border-bottom: 55px solid #ff6;
    height: 1px;
}

#wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
    width:200%;
    overflow:hidden;
    background: #ff0000;
}

#box1, #box2, {
    width:50%;
    float:left;
    color: #000;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18011727/css3-transform-property-not-working-as-expected-in-chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transitions on the same page, are ignored by default. http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-transitions.html

From link above:
**Using same page transition** 
Transitions to the current active page are ignored by default but can be enabled by using the allowSamePageTransition option of the $.mobile.changePage method. Note that not all transitions will work as expected and may end in an impractical result.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to find an alternate method to display this