# CSS3: transform property not working as expected in chrome

Tags: jquery, css, css-transforms

I am trying to achieve the below thing ..And its working pretty well in firefox but the same css

[image: Expected Result in Firefox]

working in chrome is somewhat like this shown below

[image: Screenshot in Chrome]

I think `-webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;` doesnt work in chrome or its working but not as expected

> [Demo Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W9uPE/4/)

```
#flyDiv {
    width:720px;
    height:420px;
    transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    perspective: 300;
    transform: perspective(300px) rotateX(15deg);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(300px) rotateX(15deg);
}
```

Comment: Works for me (Chrome 28)

Comment: Works for me using Chrome Canary

Comment: Looks fine in Chrome versino 28.0.1500.71 m JSBin version here - http://jsbin.com/opejoq/1

Comment: Yeah scrolling works but the shape of div is not as expected in firefox

Comment: my chrome version is  28.0.1500.95 m

Comment: I have exactly the same Chrome version and it works for me. May be you should try clearing cache data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably I have found an error ..This is hardware issue I have checked in many computers and found that pc in which their are graphic cards present they are the one who can run them smoothly as they are `hardware accelerated` ..Otherwise the slantness differs bcoz its `software accelerated`..

just check ur pc config by `chrome://gpu` in address bar and u will find the diff

**Following image is that in which its running fine...**
[image: Hardware Accelerated PC]

**Following image is that in which its not running as expected...**
[image: Software Accelerated PC]

Anyways Thanks for your answers and comments ..One favour plz confirm me this by checking if possible ..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you are not doing it in the right way you have to use **transform-style: preserve-3d**   on the parent element  then you can transform the child. And since you are using 3d for a better performance you will need **backface-visibility: hidden;**

and you ve to use `-webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;` or just user prefixfree from LEA VEROU

http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/

parent:

```
 section#transform3d{
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;       
        }
```

child

```
#flyDiv {
    width:720px;
    height:420px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    -webkit-perspective: 300px;
    -moz-perspective: 300px;
    perspective: 300px;

    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    /*  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 10s; 
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%; */
    -webkit-transform: perspective(300px) rotateX(15deg);
    -moz-transform: perspective(300px) rotateX(15deg);
    transform: perspective(300px) rotateX(15deg);
}
```

demo :  http://jsfiddle.net/kougiland/W9uPE/6/

read mor here : http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/