# Border percentage width

Tags: css

is there any option set pseudo element(:before) border width(height) same as container(with fluid height) height without px units?

html:

```
<div id="container">
test
</div>
```

css:

```
#container{
    width:50%;
    height:300px; /**without*/
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;  
}

#container:before{
    height:100%;
    width:auto;
    position:absolute;
    border-top: 300px solid #05ed08; /**without px*/
    border-left: 45px solid transparent;
    border-right: 45px solid transparent; 
    content:"";    
    right:-45px;
    left:-45px;
    z-index:-1;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3pqFE/5/

Comment: Your question is not clear, but if you try to drawing shapes with CSS, you can try this: http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: @ArbaouiMehdi but without chance use fluid height of container

Comment: What type of shapes you like drawing with CSS ?

Comment: If you like to increase `height` and `border-top` simultaneously, you can using jQuery

Comment: You can see it in fiddle?! somenthing like reversed trapezoid. sharpness of angles depends on container height. p.s.: your link is same as my example

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18011727/css3-transform-property-not-working-as-expected-in-chrome plz help

Comment: for now i use http://jsfiddle.net/3pqFE/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this jQuery solution, based on your first [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3pqFE/5/):

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
<div class="test"></div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Totam magni nesciunt sit consectetur dolore quos veritatis aliquam modi consequuntur quibusdam ratione molestias earum optio asperiores nemo quam dignissimos iure recusandae?
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Totam magni nesciunt sit consectetur dolore quos veritatis aliquam modi consequuntur quibusdam ratione molestias earum optio asperiores nemo quam dignissimos iure recusandae?
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Totam magni nesciunt sit consectetur dolore quos veritatis aliquam modi consequuntur quibusdam ratione molestias earum optio asperiores nemo quam dignissimos iure recusandae?
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container{
    width:50%;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    padding: 5px;
}

.test{
    height:100%;
    width:auto;
    position:absolute;
    border-top: 300px solid #05ed08;
    border-left: 45px solid transparent;
    border-right: 45px solid transparent;   
    right:-45px;
    left:-45px;
    z-index:-1;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
var divHeight = $('div#container').height() + 10;

$('#container').css('height', divHeight+'px');
$('.test').css('border-top', divHeight+'px solid #05ed08');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UrTLU/3/

**Note**: Try adding content for seeing increasing of height.

Comment: In your case, it's impossible to adapt content to your block without increasing height and border-top,this is why i have chosen the jQuery solution